# Mongoid - querying by referenced document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a model named Ad which looks like this:

```
class Ad
  include Mongoid::Document
  referenced_in :category
end
```

and Category model:

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  referenced_in :domain
  references_many :ads
end
```

How can I select Ads by domain?
I have tried to use `Ad.where('category.domain_id' => domain.id)` but this does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that MongoDB doesn't have any way of mapping a `Category` record to an `Ad` record. All it knows is that an `Ad` record has a `category_id` field so `'category.domain_id'` will always return nothing. The dot notation inside queries works only for embedded documents, not references (which are still second-class citizens in MongoDB).

So to solve your problem, you'll need 2 queries:

```
category_ids = Category.where(:domain_id => domain.id).map(&:_id)
Ad.where(:category_id.in => category_ids)
```

Comment: yes, but I also need to get all subcategories of category(including sub-sub and sub-sub-sub...). I have implemented it using MapReduce(after my attempt to use ids collection with recursive function).