# Mongoid query using Geocoder

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

I've been going through the mongoid docs, Geocoder docs and have asked a friend, but am still a little stuck on this. I've got two Models, Event and Place:

```
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :place
end

class Place
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :events
end
```

I've set these up so that `Event.place` and `Place.events` work fine, the thing that is throwing me is incorporating the Geocoder near method into queries. Currently `Place.near(location)` works fine, what I'm wanting to do is query Events by their location, so `Event.place.near(location)`

I've tried looking at things like:

`@events = Event.where('event.place' => near(location)`

`@events = Event.where(place.near(location))`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: using the info on this page, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364213/mongoid-querying-by-referenced-document I've come up with this solution, but would love to see something more elegant if it's possible: `place_ids = Place.near(@ocation).map(&:_id)
  @events = Event.where(:place_id.in => place_ids`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this to be

```
place.near(location).events.all
```

and you can query the events like

```
place.near(location).events.where(....
```

Comment: `place.events` only seems to work after assigning to a var, so `@places = Place.all` and then `@places.each do |place| @events += place.events end` `.events` can't be called directly on the Place model. Or so I've found. But after assigning the model to a variable, you can no longer query it as a model.

Answer (score 0):

A very useful gem you could benefit for when dealing with Geocoder and locations in general within mongoDB :

https://github.com/ryanong/mongoid_spacial